# How would I simulate the multi stage fitness test?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How would I determine a score, per character, on this test?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_fitness_test

I would like to take the character's statistics and possibly a die roll and then determine a score on the test.

The key to understanding this test is that you run back and forth between two points 20 meters (66 feet) apart at a steadily increasing speed until you can no longer keep up with the required speed and miss a waypoint. (Look for "bleep test" on youtube if you need to see it - everybody calls it that because the full name is too much of a mouthful).

This is not determined by your maximum running speed (it is well below sprinting speeds for an athlete) but on your short term endurance. It is somehow related to Constitution and possibly Athletics skill (although that uses Strength for some reason).

Comment: This depends a lot on the accuracy you need. Do you need an actual hard number, or is it something you would want to compare? The reason I ask is that it is much more reasonable to create a comparison test as opposed to a hard number (which would have to be tuned, &c.) The rest can be roleplayed. So, I suppose my question is: what do you need the results for?

Comment: @Chad The question isn't clear on the level of granularity of result required, how long the test should take to resolve, and how deep the simulation should go. Does the OP want the high drama of constantly worrying if "this next lap" will be their last? Does he or she want to get a "you scored 8" type of result quickly and move on? We don't know, and there's so many possible answers between those extremes that we won't know what to vote for.

Comment: @GMJoe - I think a good answer would actually explain all of that.  The question is how would you perform the tests and come up with a result.  I think the answer would present a solution that minimizes the number of actual rolls while giving still a decent result.

Comment: I guess I am disappointed that this SE has decided that since this is not an easy question to answer we are going to put it on hold.  The question is clear.  I want to implement a challenge that is a common fitness test, how can I do this in a way that is going to be fun and more than just a series of seemingly endless die rolls.

Answer (score 2):

If anything, a PC's "constitution" (you haven't specified a system, so being system-agnostic as best I can) would provide the best score, and depending on your system could be percentaged/modified to fit the scoring for the test.

If you need dice rolls, you could make the PCs roll "constitution tests", starting with some positive modifiers, i.e. +5/+25% etc. every subsequent test then reduces the test modifier by -1/-5%. If the system has modifiers based on the "constitution" value, e.g. D&D, they would be included as well.

People keep testing until they fail (which might prove humourous if the 20+ CON barbarian-type fails his first test on a natural 1 and the 10 CON wizard-type completes the test) or everyone tests a set number of times and successes are calculated as a "percentage" of the total number of tests.

Unfortunately, I'm can't avoid answering this with an opinion; the nature is something you'd inevitably have to houserule.  I've never seen anyone rule on this before, so its only my opinion and experience making houserules that provide the above advice, so feel free to ignore this if it doesn't help you make your own rules.

It has to be said, this question needs to be more specific (system to test in, circumstances/explanation for why test would be performed) to get a better answer, and the subject might be seen as redundant; why perform the test when the actual "constitution" value is an indicator of their probable performance?